# Can many Users open a SP with a TempTable in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

After a user is logged into his system and opens my progamm he can see data from a database depending on his WindowsUsername(I wrote a little stored procedure for that).

This Data comes from a query with a temporary Table (#temp). My question is now, if many users use this programm, after opening it they would all try to build the #temp Table within the stored procedure. Is that even possible?? Because if i try to build a tempTable with the same name the server gives me an error. Do i have to give dynamic TempTable names maybe according to the user who is logged in??? Or is there another better option?
MS-SQL Server

Comment: What RDBMS we are talking about here?

Comment: i am working with ms sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a true temp table within a stored procedure (SP) then the temp table is created/only exists during the execution of the SP. If the sp is run multiple times by multiple users at the same time the temp table is created multiple times and stored in its own memory space for each user.

The results returned to each user will be unique and each copy of the temp table will not see the temp table from other sp calls.

If you are testing in a query window by creating the temp table twice then you will get an error.

To prove that the above works schedule the SP to run twice at the same time passing a different user id. You will get two different result sets.

Answer (score 2):

- A local temp table (one `#TableName`) is per session/connection
- Many users can not share a session/connection

So, a local temp table in a stored procedure is safe for may concurrent users

On the other hand you use a global temp table (`##TableName`) then it is visible to world+dog

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986.aspx) (my bold)

> There are two types of temporary tables: local and global. **Local temporary tables are visible only to their creators during the same connection to an instance of SQL Server as when the tables were first created or referenced. Local temporary tables are deleted after the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server.** Global temporary tables are visible to any user and any connection after they are created, and are deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server.